# How do I add a column to Kendo Grid that is editable when you add a row but not when you edit a row?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid using MVC and I'm using a pop out editor with a partial view for the editor template.  I want to enable editing of a field only when adding a new row, but not when editing a row.  I tried handling this in the onclick event for the buttons but it's too early and the controls aren't in the DOM yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to the [`edit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit) event of the Grid. Then, obtain the edited data item (`e.model`) and check if it is a new one, or an existing one via [`e.model.isNew()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-isNew).

If the user is editing an existing row, [access the respective editor](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/access-editor-control) inside the edit container (`e.container`) and make it readonly, or hide it.